# Changing OpenGL vertex attributes in a sample

Tags: c, ios, opengl-es, shader, vertex

I am using [this tutorial / sample](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios) to do some basic object tracking on the iPhone. Everything works fine, I even tweaked the performance a whole lot, but I am still stuck with one problem.

The basic problem is that I do not understand OpenGL well enough and I should be punished for shamefully taking sample code and turning it into something that works for me. As a matter of fact I am being punished;

The sample shows how to render (with shaders) the iPhone's camera into an offscreen texture in order to be able to process it and show it on screen. Now I have figured out that it draws the texture/layer using an array of vertex attributes (a principle I barely understand, despite my Google searches).

The vertex array's are as follows:

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,
        1.0f,  1.0f,
};

static const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
        1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,  1.0f,
        0.0f,  0.0f,
};
```

I have also figured out that these vertex attributes can alter the orientation of the drawn texture. The texture is now drawn in portrait, which means that if I keep my iPhone in landscape (which I desire), and let the views rotate along, everything I see on the screen is a camera with a 90 degree angle.

I think I narrowed the problem down enough to blame these vertexes and I have been messing around with their values somewhat but without any acceptable result.

Is there anybody out there who can help me draw the texture in landscape?

P.S: if I inverse the values of 'squareVerticles' I am able to get a 180 degree rotated picture. But I want the texture to be rotated 90 degrees, not 180.

Comment: Don't forget that mirroring is different from rotating 180 degrees.

Comment: @Midas, you are absolutely right! changed it.

Comment: If you've "tweaked the performance a whole lot", would you mind posting what you did to improve the performance as a comment on my article?  My implementation there was not optimal, and I'd be interested to see what could be done to speed it up.  I know that I need to replace the color averaging of the scene with an on-GPU operation to provide the biggest boost, but I'm curious as to what else you found.

Comment: @Brad, I am sure planning to share it with you, have to refine it a bit. Also it is not very practical for precise-object tracking.. I'll post it at the bottom of your tutorial soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that your screen has normalized coordinates that go from `-1.0,-1.0` (left, bottom) to `1.0, 1.0`. The first array specifies the coordinates of the vertices of a square (presumably as a triangle strip, because they are given in a "Z" fashion).

The second array specifies the texture coordinates. Same thing, except that they are in the `0.0, 1.0` range.

So, to rotate 90 degrees clockwise:

```
1.0f, 0.0f
0.0f, 0.0f
1.0f, 1.0f
0.0f, 1.0f
```

anticlockwise:

```
0.0f, 1.0f
1.0f, 1.0f
0.0f, 0.0f
1.0f, 0.0f
```

I hope that works!

Comment: I'm sorry I need some more guidance on this one. If I change the squareVerticles with the values you gave, I get a small square at the top of my screen (which used to be fullscreen with the previous values) that shows me something that is indeed rotated 90 degrees from its original point. I want it to be fullscreen. can you elaborate on how the values relate to points on the screen, I want to be able to understand it. Thanks.

Comment: No, I meant you should change `textureVertices`, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You sir, are the best :-D the second row of values works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MiRAGe - If it helps, try drawing these out on paper and mark the texture coordinates next to the corresponding vertices.   It's what I did to come up with the values to begin with.  I think it'll make sense why things are laid out this way.